# Putting colour in an element after an event has been handled

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, addeventlistener

I am trying to fill an element, once its been clicked to a block of colour in jquery but i can't work it out :(

I have an event listener on the div element and in the console its saying it's been clicked, or hovered over which is great, but i need help with blocking out a colour once the element has been clicked on.

I have this right now

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "div" ).on({
     "click": function() { console.log( "clicked!" ); },
     "mouseover": function() { console.log( "hovered!" );
  });
});
```

Any help would be amazing!!!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use ;

```
$( "div" ).on({
     "click": function() { 
           $(this).addClass( "clickClass" )  
      },
     "mouseover": function() {
         $(this).addClass( "hoverClass" )  
      }
});
```

Then in css, add how you want the element to look for each event

```
.clickClass{
   //your css here ex. background: purple;
 }

.hoverClass{
   //your css here ex. background: green;
 }
```

Make sure to also add a `mouseout` event, so when your mouse is taken off the `div`, you remove `hoverClass`

Comment: Thanks for replying but that still hasn't worked. I need the element to turn a block of colour.

Comment: That is accomplished by adding a `background` tag in the css

Comment: What if i wanted to not have it on a div but a class name?

Comment: Sorry, not so sure what you're asking. Please clarify, and I'll try to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery css function to achieve this. It can accept hex values also
[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


$( "div" ).on({
"click": function() { 
$(this).css('background-color','red');

console.log( "clicked!" ); },
"mouseover": function() {
$(this).css('background-color','blue');
console.log( "hovered!" );
  }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
content
</div>
```

**Another Solution**
 in script file

```
$( "div" ).on({
     "click": function() { 
           $(this).addClass( "redBg" )  
      },
     "mouseover": function() {
         $(this).addClass( "blueBg" )  
      }
});
```

You need add these following css styles (you can use hex or rgb values also)

```
.redBg{
  background-color:red;
 }

.blueBg{
   background-color:blue;
 }
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to want select element by class instead of tag name, you can do as follow:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


$( ".changeClr" ).on({
"click": function() { 
$(this).css('background-color','red');

console.log( "clicked!" ); },
"mouseover": function() {
$(this).css('background-color','blue');
console.log( "hovered!" );
  }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changeClr">
content
</div>
<div class="changeClr">
content2
</div>
```

Comment: What if i wanted to not have it on a div but a class name?